Factor analysis: removal of missing values in parallel analysis
I am performing exploratory factor analysis in R.
I run a parallel analysis:
fa.parallel(scaled_FA.df,fm='ml', fa='fa', use='pairwise')

where 'use' describes how to handle missing values.
The result is 2 factors.
I run factor analysis in lavaan with 2 factors:
   fit2 <- efa(data = scaled_FA.df, nfactors = 2, rotation= 'oblimin')
   summary(fit2)

but I notice that this only seems to use 40 out of the 73 observations (i.e., excludes missing vaues:

I don't understand why there is an option to handle missing values in parallel analysis if they are removed anyway in the factor analysis stage? This is problematic as I am receiving a warning that some eigenvalues are negative and this may be a symptom that the model is not identified.
**Note: I realise that I have a small sample- I am just interested in what is going on here **

This may get clossed for being about coding, but the documentation for fa.parallel does not mention a use argument.  And I'm not sure what you would want the program to do. // You might need multiple imputation, but you have to be careful as the signs of factors are aribttrary.

fa.parallel and efa are in different packages. Chances are their implementations are not coordinated, so they may well handle things in different manners. The question seems to suggest you expect them to be somehow "unified".

I don't think this needs to be closed. It's about what happens when you compute a covariance or correlation matrix based on pairwise missingness versus case-wise or list-wise deletion

https://lavaan.ugent.be/tutorial/est.html#missing-values ; https://personality-project.org/r/psych/help/corFiml.html

You have two options. The issue is how a correlation matrix (or covariance matrix) is computed with the 'pairwise' option. Each entry of the matrix will have a potentially different $N_{pairs}$ associated with it, which  will wreak a bit of havoc with the use of any fit indices that are based on complete-data $N$.

Use the fa() function from the psych package for EFA, and supply the same use = 'pairwise' argument to obtain the same correlation matrix for the two analyses. You will not get as many fit indices, and many shouldn't be used anyway in this case, since you're doing exploratory analyses.
lavaan also allows you to use pairwise option via the argument missing = 'pairwise'. This, however, will likely alter the fit indices, potentially making them disappear as you will now, not have a consistent sample size across all observed variables.


Thank you this is an incredibly helpful answer.

My pleasure ;).
